# jQuery Iterate previous and next siblings till first mismatch

Tags: jquery, html, css

ok the problem is as following , I have a div with some siblings positioned after , and before  the div for example:

```
<div id="parent">

<div class="invalid"></div><!-- break iteration here !-->
<div class="operand"></div>
<div class="constant"></div>
<div class="operator"></div>
<div class="operand"></div><!--this is the target div i want its siblings !-->
<div class="constant"></div>
<div class="constant"></div>
<div class="operator"></div>
<div class="invalid"></div><!-- break iteration here !-->

</div>
```

i want to iterate all siblings of class "constant" or class "operator" (next and previous siblings) , till first mismatch in both directions.

Tried so far:

```
.next( ".constant .operator" ).appendto("#mydiv")
.prev( ".constant .operator" ).appendto("#mydiv")
```

the problem is to go beyond next siblings as well , and stop at first mismatch

Comment: .next( ".constant .operator" ).appendto("#mydiv")                 .prev( ".constant .operator" ).appendto("#mydiv") , the problem is to go beyond next siblings as well , and stop at first mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best answer for this , is using [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) , and [`.prevUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/), before asking the question , i didn't know such methods exist !

Comment: Ack! I totally forgot about `nextUntil`! This is by far the better answer, I suggest un-accepting mine and (when the two-day period is up) accepting your own instead.